# SOAP API having issue on Salesforce upsert call

Tags: soap

When doing Salesforce upsert call we are getting below response in Production and (lower environments) for almost all the requests sent.

After initial investigation, email, phone number and DOB fields look fine.

Can you please let us know the meaning of the response and what's wrong in the request?

This is happening to almost all the cases since past few days. In the past, sometimes when we retry the service call it works and goes through, but now it is "failing" giving the response above.

I noticed that we are within limit. The current did not exceed the limit. So Why we are getting this Service Response and unable to do upserts?

```
  Service Request
  <ns1:upsert xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
  instance" xmlns:ns1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" 
  xmlns:ns2="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"> 
  <ns1:externalIDFieldName>External_Application_ID_
  c</ns1:externalIDFieldName> <ns1:sObjects> 
  <ns2:type>Lead</ns2:type> 
  <ns2:RecordTypeId>01228000000Czge</ns2:RecordTypeId> 
  <ns2:Id xsi:nil="true"/> 
  <ns2:FirstName>XXXX</ns2:FirstName> 
  <ns2:External_Application_ID
  c>OAMQ0000520389</ns2:External_Application_ID
  c> <ns2:Application_Status
  c>Resolved-Finalised</ns2:Application_Status
  c> <ns2:Email>XXXX@bigpond.com</ns2:Email> 
  <ns2:LastName>XXXX</ns2:LastName> 
  <ns2:Salutation>Mr</ns2:Salutation> 
  <ns2:Status>Open</ns2:Status> 
  <ns2:LeadSource>Digital</ns2:LeadSource> 
  <ns2:Referral_Source
  c>OurWebsite</ns2:Referral_Source
  c> <ns2:PreferredContactTime
  c>ASAP</ns2:PreferredContactTime
  c> <ns2:OwnerId>00G28000000IaQQ</ns2:OwnerId> 
  <ns2:Web_To_Lead_Form_Name
  c>Multi-product Application</ns2:Web_To_Lead_Form_Name
  c> <ns2:MobilePhone>0420 000 000</ns2:MobilePhone> 
  <ns2:Date_of_Birth
  c>1960-04-20</ns2:Date_of_Birth
  c> <ns2:Product_s
  c>Product;</ns2:Product_s
  c> <ns2:Brand
  c>ABC</ns2:Brand
  c> <ns2:Sub_Brand
  c>ABC</ns2:Sub_Brand
  c> <ns2:Unsubscribe
  c></ns2:Unsubscribe
  c> <ns2:Retrieve
  c></ns2:Retrieve
  c> <ns2:MAC
  c>12345678</ns2:MAC
  c> <ns2:CampaignId></ns2:CampaignId> 
  <ns2:InstantDecisionCode
  c></ns2:InstantDecisionCode
  c> <ns2:UID
  c></ns2:UID
  c> <ns2:External_Case_Id
  c>OAP-123456</ns2:External_Case_Id
  c> <ns2:Campaign_Id
  c></ns2:Campaign_Id
  c> <ns2:Salesforce_Record_Id
  c></ns2:Salesforce_Record_Id
  c> <ns2:Address_Line_1
  c>40 Burmingham RD</ns2:Address_Line_1
  c> <ns2:Address_Line_2
  c></ns2:Address_Line_2
  c> <ns2:Address_Line_3
  c></ns2:Address_Line_3
  c> <ns2:Address_State
  c>NSW</ns2:Address_State
  c> <ns2:Address_City
  c>WEST ALBURY</ns2:Address_City
  c> <ns2:Address_Country
  c>AUSTRALIA</ns2:Address_Country
  c> <ns2:Address_PostalCode
  c>2640</ns2:Address_PostalCode_c> </ns1:sObjects> 
  </ns1:upsert>
```

Service Response

```
 <LimitInfoHeader xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><limitInfo> 
 <current>219155</current><limit>17236800</limit><type>API REQUESTS</type> 
 </limitInfo></LimitInfoHeader>
```

*****I changed the Address for confidentiality

Comment: This looks like SOAP API than web2leads

Comment: The inclusion of `LimitInfoHeader` in the response does not mean the call failed, it's an informational element. Even without reading the docs, you can make an educated guess about the meaning of this element: the current value (`219155`) is far less than your limit (`17236800`). If your call is failing, it's for other reasons.

Comment: Why this shows on Service Response and does not shows a Success Response on Salesforce upsert, Service Request is done from Pega to Salesforce?